# Android Studio, design view empty

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using 1.4. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall again. still same problem. any solution?
[image]

Comment: Did you try switching the Android version in the dropdown menu? The one that says "22"? I had a similar issue because my sdk for 22 was corrupted somehow.

Comment: i tried, nothing came out... the design view seems to be working for my old existing file. however newly created file is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try just building the project: Build -> Make Project

If that doesn't work try cleaning the project: Build -> Clean Project

That happened to me as well and all I had to do was build the project. Then it was able to render it.

Comment: Helped in my case. Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: "Rebuild Project" worked for me.  Essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

Go to app-res-values->styles.xml then;
Change,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I just upgraded to Android Studio 1.5 and I ran into this same issue with new created projects. I tried invalidate the cache and rebuild the project. Sometimes that will fix the initial rendering, but any changes I make to the layout will not be reflected on the Design view.

The problem seems to be related to the embedded layout mechanism. After creating a new project (with Blank Activity), I got `content_main.xml` to display by removing the line `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"`. Similarly, remove `<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>` from `activity_main.xml` and the Design view should render properly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to remove android studio cache folders after uninstalling? they located on
`C:\Users\<username>\.android`, `..\.AndroidStudio1.4`, `..\.gradle`.
And then try to install studio again

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

1. Clean project
2. Build project
3. Close .xml files
4. Reopen them

That worked for me

5. Close android studio and reopen. Then rebuild project.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation there was a silent error in my activity .xml file.

I accidentally positioned an item outside of my `GridLayout` (the child's `layout_row`/`layout_column` was too high). I'd expect Android Studio to report mistakes like this, but instead the design view just stops working.

So if your design view stops working and the other answers don't help, you might have an unreported error in your .xml file.